# How to read from the screen in flutter?

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart

I am developing a flutter app that uses the camera to scan a barcode and shows it on the screen.

I added `barcode_scan: ^1.0.0` to my dependencies and it works perfectly but I have a few questions:

1. Does flutter support reading from the screen? (like reading the barcode digits that I got on the screen)
2. do I need firebase to store a database of products to match the scanned barcodes with it or can I store the barcodes in the application?
   I ultimately aim to read a barcode, look for the product and display some info about it [This is the result I get after scanning a barcode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BDVXc.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For 1. The package you are using [barcode_scan: ^1.0.0](https://pub.dev/documentation/barcode_scan/latest/), provides a way to read barcode using your camera, To read barcode from camera, an example on how you can read the barcode

```
import 'package:barcode_scan/barcode_scan.dart';

void main() async {
  var result = await BarcodeScanner.scan();
  
  print(result.type); // The result type (barcode, cancelled, failed)
  print(result.rawContent); // The barcode content
  print(result.format); // The barcode format (as enum)
  print(result.formatNote); // If a unknown format was scanned this field contains a note
}
```

if you wants to read from images in your images folder/gallery, you have to create the code to load those image  [qr_code_tools](https://pub.dev/packages/qr_code_tools) package can help you to read those, an example

```
String _data = '';

  void _getQrByGallery() {
    Observable<File>.fromFuture(
            ImagePicker.pickImage(source: ImageSource.gallery))
        .flatMap((File file) {
      return Observable<String>.fromFuture(
        QrCodeToolsPlugin.decodeFrom(file.path),
      );
    }).listen((String data) {
      setState(() {
        _data = data;
      });
    }).onError((dynamic error, dynamic stackTrace) {
      setState(() {
        _data = '';
      });
    });
  }
```

For 2. You can save anywhere, but if you are calling from an API and are updating products info than store database remotely.

Answer (score 1):

To get the barcode:

```
String barcode = await BarcodeScanner.scan();
```

As for using Firebase, you should definitely use a database if the products are ever going to change. If the products and product info is set in stone and will never change, might as well just put it in the app.